# How to test In app auto renewing subscription

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

> Hello, All Currently I developing an App that has An app auto-recurring subscription so I implement a code for that but right now Google Play pauses auto-renewing subscriptions, free trials in India to comply with RBI regulations so I am not able to test my code for the subscription. App design for US country Please let me know how can I test my code.

Comment: Have you got the solution for this question?

Comment: I check it through the client's device and it's working fine

Comment: Is the client device located in US region? I am testing the application in an android emulator device... I am doing the InApp Purchase  testing in india where I am not getting free trial or even the subscription is not getting auto renewed